# Sqlite query, finding row value

Tags: sqlite

I am having a beginner question about writing a Sqlite query that I can't seem to figure out:

So you have a table called "D", one column that is called "PersonName", one that is called "DrinkName" and one that is called "CountryName" and you are now looking too see which PersonName has had all DrinkName where CountryName='France' for example.

I have tried by using HAVING COUNT in a numerous different ways but it never works out and I didn't really know where to turn, which is why I am asking you here! Sorry if this question isn't relevant to Stackoverflow or hard to understand, it's my first time here :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try the exercises at sqlzoo to get you up and running

Comment: Post the table structure, some data sample, and an example of expected results. Also show what you did, and what errors you get. Simply saying "it never works out" is not an accurate description of your problem. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)